# how to test spring web application in jmeter

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, jmeter

I am new to jmeter and I have Spring web application project in Eclipse juno and the server is tomcat server. I want to use JMeter to do some performance testing on the application.I did some search in google and found simple test plans but in my project we have login screen which redirects to other screens.How to redirect my login screen to other pages? Any reference will help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the tutorial / documentation of [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf).

You should not setup your whole test by hand. If you have a complex web application, especially one using a framework like Spring or Seam, you should record a flow through your web application. JMeter offers a proxy for that.
You enable this proxy in JMeter and configure it in your browser (more about that in the linked document above).

After you did the recording you have to handle those variable values like jSessionId, userId and all that and define some variables / rewrites in your requests.

For performance testing you then usually add random timing, loops and parallel executions of your flow. This is all according to your needs, so play around with that and come back with specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 areas you should be aware of:

**1. Create a test suite according to your business logic.** You can do it via

- manual requests building using HTTP Samplers
- using JMeter HTTP Proxy to record your flow as Matthias suggests
- using [Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi/details?hl=en) to record test script right in browser

Any approach should produce a number of more or less sensible requests. You may wish to make your scripts more like to real browser by considering adding following:

- HTTP Header  Manager - to simulate user agent(s)
- HTTP Cache Manager - to simulate browser cache
- Retrieve all embedded resources parameter of HTTP Sampler combined with Use concurrent pool size to simulate browser asynchronous calls to images, css and javascript files
- HTTP Cookie Manager - to handle cookies

  1. **Deal with logins and sessions**

The easiest way to achieve this is to add [HTTP Cookie manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to the thread group. Make sure that you have **CookieManager.save.cookies=true** property set. The property lives in *jmeter.properties* file under /bin folder of your JMeter installation and defaults to "false". After enabling it you'll get more "realistic" behavior and will be able to access cookies as JMeter variables prefixed with COOKIE_

JMeter variables can be viewed via Debug Sampler + View Results Tree listener (which is the best way of debugging your tests) and be referenced in any part of test as ${VARIABLENAME}

Comment: Thank you for reply. In our application we are not maintaining cache. We are maintaining only session throughout application i.e., displaying username in navigation bar.

Comment: I successfully recorded the flow and observed some results in graphs. Now, I want to test for 10 users accessing the web portal performing different tasks on it. Moreover our portal consists of search and create functionality only. So, I want a test plan to test for 10 users performing different tasks like user1 searching records,user2 just viewing the search  results,user3 creating record ,user4 deleting the record and so on. Can you help me for writing test plan for above scenario.